# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Academia's [second moderator election](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the moderator is:

[image: Wrzlprmft]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4963713824063488/0).

Comment: Congratulations, @Wrzlprmftl. Next time I hope to see Massimo as moderator too.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Congrats!

Comment: why can't more candidates become mod, and why don't old ones be replaced? (I just ask about the system, not saying who deserves who don't)

Comment: @Ooker: We don't require moderators to run for re-election because moderators sometimes need to make unpopular decisions. Generally we run elections as needed when the site grows or an existing mod steps down. It's not unusual for excellent candidates to not get elected. However, it's not unusual for them to get elected the next time we select moderators.

Comment: @JonEricson so the election doesn't run annually? And it's the algorithm to select which candidates success, not because only one can be chosen at a time, is that correct?

Comment: @Ooker No, elections are not run annually. In fact, the previous one here was in 2014. If you look at the [election page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/2) you can see (on the right) that there was just one position available, and that's why only one moderator was selected.

Answer (score 16):

*Non c'è due senza tre* (poor man's translation: from two follows three): An Italian saying that welcomes your well-deserved third moderator appointment Wrzlprmft! Congratulations and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 8):

Congrats Wrzlprmft. It’s well deserved and I think Academia is in excellent hands.

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations! I wish you a good moderatorship.

Answer (score 3):

Congrats Wrzlprmft.

Welcome to Academia cleanup zone. Academians are waiting for....

[image]

Comment: It’s not that bad. This is a very orderly community.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft so we hire you for nothing? :P